# Getting error "Invalid string: must provide a Kana variation." in stripe connect account address of Japan country

Tags: stripe-payments

I have created a Stripe connect account but it needs additional information eg. Kana Name, Kanji Name and Address Information. Stripe connect account will not be activated until these required information are filled correctly. Please see below screenshot:

[image]

Is there any one who can provide me correct Japan address for Stripe Connect?

I have already tried below solutions:

1) https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information

```
// 〒150-0001 東京都渋谷区神宮前3-27-15 FLAG 3A
{
  "country": "JP",
  "legal_entity": {
    "address_kana": {
      "country": "JP", // 2-letter country code
      "postal_code": "1500001", // Zip/Postal Code
      "state": "ﾄｳｷﾖｳﾄ", // Prefecture
      "city": "ｼﾌﾞﾔ", // City/Ward
      "town": "ｼﾞﾝｸﾞｳﾏｴ 1-", // Town/cho-me
      "line1": "5-8", // Block/Building number
      "line2": "ｼﾞﾝｸﾞｳﾏｴﾀﾜｰﾋﾞﾙﾃﾞｨﾝｸﾞ22F", // Building details (optional)
    },
    "address_kanji": {
      "country": "JP", // 2-letter country code
      "postal_code": "１５００００１", // Zip/Postal Code
      "state": "東京都", // Prefecture
      "city": "渋谷区", // City/Ward
      "town": "神宮前　１丁目", // Town/cho-me (no kanji numerals)
      "line1": "５－８", // Block/Building number
      "line2": "神宮前タワービルディング22F", // Building details (optional)
    }
  }
}
```

2) Used Japan address generator

https://www.fakeaddressgenerator.com/World_more/Japan_address_generator

Comment: I'd recommend contacting [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/email) as they can provide you with the requirements around those field, as well as likely having sample data to provide.

Comment: @taintedzodiac Thanks but they are not able to provide test address of Japan to test this functionality. I have already talked to them.

Comment: Thanks for flagging that, as the support team should definitely have a resource for this when you're using test mode. I'm going to make sure they get that, but for your specific instance, do the addresses at https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/japan-address-format-spec#examples-kanji-kana work? I'm able to enter them fine via the Dashboard, but if you're still getting issues, what exactly are you running in to? Is it that the test mode account can't be verified like if you used the "testing addresses" [from here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing)?

Answer (score 0):

**Stripe Connect: Japan Country Address**

I have found the solution a correct address of Japan country for Stripe connect account:

**A. Dashboard (Manually)**

**1) Address (Kanji)**

```
Postal code : 1040031
Prefecture : 東京都
Address line 1 : 中央区
Address line 2 : 京橋
City or ward : 2丁目
Town or cho-me : (enter address if there are address after 2丁目)
```

**2) Address (Kana)**

```
Postal code : 1040031
Address line 1 : チュウオウク
Address line 2 : キョウバシ
City or ward : 2チョウメ
Town or cho-me : (enter address if there are address after 2丁目)
```

**B. Adding Address By API**

```
 "address_kana": {
      "country": "JP", // 2-letter country code
      "postal_code": "1040031", // Zip/Postal Code
      "state": "ﾄｳｷﾖｳﾄ", // Prefecture
      "city": "ﾁｭｳｵｳｸ", // City/Ward
      "town": "ｷｮｳﾊﾞｼ2-", // Town/cho-me
      "line1": "（"enter address if there are address after 2"), // Block/Building number
      "line2": "enter a building name", // Building details (optional)
    },
    "address_kanji": {
      "country": "JP", // 2-letter country code
      "postal_code": "１０４００３１", // Zip/Postal Code
      "state": "東京都", // Prefecture
      "city": "中央区", // City/Ward
      "town": "京橋　2丁目", // Town/cho-me (no kanji numerals)
      "line1": "enter address if there are address after 2", // Block/Building number
      "line2": "enter a building name",
```

Also, you can refer to the link below when inputting JP address :

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information#addresses-in-japan

This worked for me. I hope this helps!